# Creating a div / panel with a side bar in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a card layout using panel similar to this [image]

which has a side bar and only body of the panel with no paddings.

How to achieve the same layout in bootstrap, please help me.

I tried with this:

```
<div class="card">
         <div class="card-block ">
           <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: yellowgreen"> hello</div> 
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide some code of what you have tried so far...

Comment: I'm trying using card layout component,

source: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/